# Azure Analysis Services deploying model from on-prem Oracle database

Tags: azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

Hi I have an Oracle database 11g 11.2.0.4, I have downloaded many clients and ODAC tools, finally I got the 32 bit Oracle runtime 11.2.0.4 and XCopy ODAC for 11.2.0.4 32-bit version.

I have managed to install the gateway, registered it on Azure Analysis services, have also connected to the database, retrieved tables and data using Visual Studio 2017. I am able to build the project on VS2017, but when I want to deploy the project I get this error which is frustrating because doesn't say much:

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'An error occurred during On-Premise Gateway related activity. Additional error details: DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError

Received error payload from gateway service with ID 396333: Async operation 777b2521-cea2-46a7-a364-9f9c80e1b816 is faulted with [0]Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Diagnostics.MashupDataAccessValueException: Mashup expression evaluation error. Reason: .

GatewayPipelineErrorCode=DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError

GatewayVersion=3000.2.52

Reason= --->

[1]Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Diagnostics.GatewayPipelineWrapperException: Substituted: MashupValueException:<pi>Microsoft.Data.Mashup.MashupValueException (0x80004005): The provider being used is deprecated: 'System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.'. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=272376 to install the official provider.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** To fix this issue, download and install the Oracle client SDK.

If you do not have the Oracle client installed, you will see an error when you try to create or use the connection:

The provider being used is deprecated: 'System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.'. Please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=272376 to install the official provider.

You get the above error if the Oracle client SDK is not installed on the machine where the on-premises data gateway is running.

**As a prerequisites:** To connect to Oracle, you will also need to install the Oracle client software on the machine where you have installed the on-premises data gateway.  Specifically, the Oracle Database connection requires the installation of the 64-bit Oracle Data Provider for .NET.  You can use the following link to download and install the Oracle client:

[64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Hope this helps.